# How to display list of patients in a aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, object

I am new to Salesforce and I currently want to display the list of existing patients in a `aura component` using the `lightning datatable`. So ,there are many objects in salesforce like Account, Lead, Candidate Patient, EHR Patient etc. I couldn't find out which object represent a patient. So, my question is  which object represent a patient or which object should I choose to display?

Comment: I think it should be 'EhrPatient__c' object, it has all the demographic details of the patient.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Health Cloud documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_data_model.htm)?